# Python/Django: __dict__ attribute error message when adding custom fields to UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django

This error occurs because I have tried to add custom fields to UserCreationForm. I have now made my two custom fields—**cristin** and **rolle**—but when I press the signup button, I get the following error message: **AttributeError at /accounts/signup/ – 'tuple' object has no attribute '__dict__'.**

(However, the new user is actually registered and is visible in the admin panel).

In my **models.py** file, I have:

```
...

class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

class Userextended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cristin = models.IntegerField()
    rolle = models.CharField(max_length=100)

...
```

In my **forms.py** file, I have:

```
...
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    cristin = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    rolle = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)
    class Meta():
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2')
        model = User

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Username'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Adress'
        self.fields['first_name'].label = 'First name'
        self.fields['last_name'].label = 'Last name'
        self.fields['cristin'].label = 'Cristin ID'
        self.fields['rolle'].label = 'Role'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and Userextended without database save")
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user_profile = Userextended(user=user,cristin=self.cleaned_data['cristin'],rolle=self.cleaned_data['rolle'])
        user_profile.save()
        return user, user_profile

...
```

The full traceback, as requested by FamousJameous in the comment, is the following:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Traceback:

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  217.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  163.         return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  79.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

File ".../anaconda/envs/fairAppEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  148.             url = self.success_url.format(**self.object.__dict__)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

What am I doing wrong and where should I place the **__dict__** that the error message is asking for?

Comment: Please post the full exception traceback. That will help others to help you.

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the field labels in your `__init__`, however, `fields` is a tuple not a dict, and even if it was a dict, that isn't the right way to do this.

You should set the `labels` as a dict in the Form's `Meta`:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    cristin = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    rolle = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)
    class Meta():
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2')
        model = User
        labels = {'username': 'Username',
                  'first_name': 'First name',
                  ...
                  'role': 'Role'}
```

No need to override the `__init__`.

Finally, your `save` method should return only the user object:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    ...
    return user
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply! I am new to Django and Python, so can you do me a major favor and show me how I should write the code?

Edit: thank you!

Comment: Moses Koledoye: unfortunately, I get the same error message. I have updated the post with the full traceback. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: @Christian Did you delete the `__init__` method?

Comment: Yes. My code is, after your suggestion:

'... labels = {'username': 'Username', 'first_name': 'First name','last_name': 'Last name', 'email': 'Email','password1': 'Password', 'password2': 'Confirm password','cristin': 'Cristin-ID', 'rolle': 'Rolle'}       def save(self, commit=True): ...'

Comment: @Christian return only `user` in your `save` method.

Comment: Moses Koledoye: you have officially saved my day! It works perfectly. Thank you for spending half an hour helping me out.